# bash: what does "!" mean as in echo "${!var}"?

Tags: bash

I see it in someone's shell script file.

```
#!/bin/bash

var=...

echo "${!var}"
```

What does "!" mean here?

Comment: [Docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html): *If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a level of variable indirection is introduced. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable* – it's good that this is not common practice, though. (PHP has something similar in [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.variable.php))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a
>   level of variable indirection is introduced. Bash uses the value of
>   the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.
>   This is known as indirect expansion.

There are exceptions to this [which are explained here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Example:

```
$ x=y
$ y=1
$ echo "${x}"
y
$ echo "${!x}"
1
```